# If I import/restore a deterministic wallet into Bitcoin Armory, how far into the dynamic addresses does it look for transactions?

Tags: wallet, armory, deterministic-wallets

I see that in Armory, I can click on "receive bitcoins" any number of times, and it generates a new as-yet unused address every time. So I could potentially send coins to address 1000, and have 999 unused addresses before it.

I'm wondering, when you import a deterministic wallet,  how many of the addresses does it check to see if they have activity?

Comment: I tested and it at least checks the first 31. Not gonna test to 1000 tho ; )

Comment: Wow that would suck if you use it your whole life then have to restore from wallet words when you are 76!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Armory will check 100 addresses, but this can be changed with `--keypool` command-line option.

Comment: Can you link a source to verify that info?

Comment: `--keypool` option is mentioned in documentation, but I couldn't find default value there, so look at [source code](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/blob/d59e38d2904e7054b3c71728439b085033e10260/armoryengine/ArmoryUtils.py#L93).